# Gson for j2me serialize and de serializae

Tags: gson

I came across GSON library for serialization and de serialization and wondering if any one knows if its J2ME version available yet..

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found out myself .... you cant user GSON as its built up using Java reflections which we dont havein in J2ME ..shite

Answer (score 0):

In order to have efficient J2ME serialization you need to implement
your custom interfaces to abstract classes.